# AMP HTML Page not valide

Tags: html, symfony, amp-html

Hi I'm trying to integrate my page for amp https://www.ampproject.org/.

I have taken the exemple in the documentation and copy paste it in my page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to check if my page is recognize as an amp valide page.

So I have created a new route and put the argument to have the debug validation in my chrome console.

But I have this errors:

> Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1491601970987
>   http://local.dev/amp/actualites/test#development=1
>
> validator.js:380 AMP validation had errors:
>
> validator.js:380 http://local.dev/amp/actualites/test:28:0 The inline
>   'style' attribute is not allowed in AMP documents. Use 'style
>   amp-custom' tag instead. (see
>   https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages)
>
> validator.js:380 http://local.dev/amp/actualites/test:28:69 The tag
>   'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.
>
> validator.js:380 http://local.dev/amp/actualites/test:28:19029 The tag
>   'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.

It seems like the page is not amp valide. But I don't understand, I just took the exemple documentation!!!

What did I do wrong?

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/debug/validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I'm using [symfony](https://symfony.com/) which is a php framework.

In dev mode the framework inject in the DOM a debug toolbar which content html, js, etc... Because of that AMP is not valid.

To resole the problem you can disable the toolbar in the `config_dev.yml` file or run the site in prod mode with `app.php`

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```